# Calculate total amount

Tags: java

When try to run I got wrong answer. What's wrong in my program?
Got answer is only for  `discount_amount` not able to get total amount.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double dicount_amount = 0;
    double discount1 = 0;
    double total = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter the cost of the software: ");
    double cost = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println(" Enter the quantity sold: ");
    int quantity = input.nextInt();
    if (cost > 0 && quantity > 0){


    if(quantity >= 10 && quantity >=19){
         discount1 = 20/100;
    }
    else if(quantity >= 20 && quantity >=49){
        discount1 = 30/100;
    }   
    else if(quantity >= 50 && quantity >=99){
         discount1 = 40/100;
    }
    else if(quantity <=100){
        discount1 = 50/100;
    }

    }
    else {

        System.out.println( " please enter valid input ");
    }

    double total1 = cost * quantity;
    dicount_amount = total1 * discount1; 
    total=  total1 - dicount_amount;

    System.out.println("Total Cost: " + total);

}
```

Comment: Can you add more details about what you're expecting the code to do, vs. what it's actually doing? You say that you're getting the wrong answer, but you don't have any details about what that answer is.

Comment: When I run your code and chose to enter `90`, and `2` I get `180`. `Enter the cost of the software: 90 Enter the quantity sold: 2 Total Cost: 180.0` If that's wrong, what is the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest thing you can do is not to divide `discount1 = 20/100;`, instead that you can set directly value `discount1 = 0.2;`

Also you should check your if statement

Example:

```
if(quantity >= 10 && quantity >=19)
```

is equal to

```
if(quantity >=19)
```

I think you want to check if quantity is between. So you should use

```
if(quantity >= 10 && quantity <=19)
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess what was your mistake? You were dividing int by int and you are excepting a double result. Typecast the division to double or do `20.0/100`. Also, I assume you are want to give a discount if the quantity is between 10 and 19. What you have been doing doesn't make sense because every time you run your program it will never fall in `else if()` statement because you are setting `quantity>=19` in if statement.

here are few changes I made in your code :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

double dicount_amount = 0;
double discount1 = 0;
double total = 0;

System.out.println("Enter the cost of the software: ");
double cost = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println(" Enter the quantity sold: ");
int quantity = input.nextInt();
if (cost > 0 && quantity > 0){


if(quantity >= 10 && quantity <=19){
     discount1 = (double)20/100;
}
else if(quantity >= 20 && quantity <=49){
    discount1 = (double)30.0/100;
}   
else if(quantity >= 50 && quantity <=99){
     discount1 = (double)40.0/100;
}
else if(quantity >=100){
    discount1 = (double)50.0/100;

}

}
 else {

    System.out.println( " please enter valid input ");
}
double total1 = cost * quantity;
dicount_amount = total1 * discount1; 
total=  total1 - dicount_amount;

System.out.println("Total Cost: " + total);
```

Output :

```
Enter the cost of the software:15 
Enter the quantity sold:16 
Total Cost: 192.0
```